# $|F|=q$ (power of a prime) , $|F(u)|=q^a , |F(v)|=q^b$ , and $F=F(u) \cap F(v)$ , then is it true that $|F(u) \cap F(v)|=q^{gcd(a,b)}$ ?

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

Let $F$ be a finite field , $|F|=q$ (power of a prime) , $|F(u)|=q^a , |F(v)|=q^b$ , and

$F=F(u) \cap F(v)$ , then is it true that $|F(u) \cap F(v)|=q^{gcd(a,b)}$ ?

Writing $|F(u) \cap F(v)|=q^d$ , I can see that $d|a , d|b$ , so $d|gcd(a,b)$ , but I am unable to conclude $d=gcd(a,b)$ . Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: The intersection takes place inside the field $E$ of size $q^{lcm(a,b)}$. One way of reaching your conclusion is to use Galois theory. After all $E/F$ is cyclic Galois, and a cyclic group has a unique subgroup of each "legal" size.

Comment: Possibly easier is to argue that if $d\mid a$ and $d\mid b$ then both $F(u)$ and $F(v)$ have a subfield of size $q^d$. Because the intersection $F(u)\cap F(v)$ only makes sense in some field like $E$, and $E$ has a **unique** subfield $K$ of size $q^d$, then the intersection must also contain $K$.